# How do multiple editors collaborate when editing a single post?

Tags: support, edits, rollbacks

I am confused by seeing my post edited by multiple users.

1. Is it possible to enter into a discussion with all of the editors? If so, how?
2. If my post is edited and I want to rollback the changes, what should I do?
3. Can I lock the post until the end of discussion?
4. Do I have any rights or abilities when it comes to my posts above and beyond those of other editors?
5. What is authority chain (hierarchy) for editing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is the FAQ?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33331/where-is-the-faq)

Comment: If someone keeps editing your post despite you rolling it back you should contact a moderator via the "flag" link.

Comment: What do you mean by "under multiple personalities/identities"?

Comment: Come chat with us.  http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/61375/multiple-identity-decision-chain-during-editing  We may be able to help better in a live chat environment.

Comment: Meta has a built in chat feature.  The link goes to a MSO chat site.  Not some random chat place.  There are already a few of the more helpful users in the room.

Answer (score 7):

In Order:

> #### 1. Is it possible to enter into a discussion with all of the editors? If so, how?

If the editors choose to leave a comment on your post, you can reply to their comments with the "@username" syntax. This will notify them about your comment. However, there is no way to guarantee that they will read or respond.

> #### 2. If my post is edited and I want to rollback the changes, what should I do?

If you feel there was an unwanted edit to your post, you go into the revision history and you click on the "rollback" link, on the version that you want to rollback to.

However, the *vast* majority of edits are made by positive community users who are attempting to help by correcting mistakes, poor grammar, or unclear statements. Keep that in mind before rolling back any changes.

> #### 3. Can I lock the post until the end of discussion?

No, there is no way to lock your post. An entire *thread* may be locked by a moderator, but that means that **no** changes can be made, including edits, comments or new answers.

> #### 4. Do I have any rights or abilities when it comes to my posts above and beyond those of other editors?

No. On your own question you are able to edit it like any other user. The only thing you are able to do that anyone else cannot is to delete it. Beyond that, you have the same privileges as other users.

> #### 5. What is authority chain (hierarchy) for editing?

- **1+** You may create posts and edit your own posts
- **100+** You may edit posts created by other users that are marked as *[community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)*
- **2000+** You may edit posts created by other users as long as they are not locked by a moderator.

Generally users with 2000 reputation can edit *any* post. For this reason, all of the content on ServerFault or StackOverflow is considered to be ["owned" by the community](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing).

Comment: And *no*. Authors cannot lock their posts.

Comment: regarding #4: authors also get one-click rollbacks (no need to load the revision list).

Answer (score 1):

If you have problems with an edit you can do a rollback, and put an comment in the edit summary explaining why, and/or put a comment under the question.

I hope that you would welcome grammar and spelling corrections, since that's a key to good communication.